# Which version of IE added hover pseudo class on any element?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

When I started working with CSS long ago there was a bug in IE that `:hover` pseudo class worked only with `a` tags. Anybody know which version of IE added `:hover` on any element?

Comment: Know Can I Use? http://caniuse.com/#search=i+u

Comment: @ZeevKatz it's say that it was added in IE7 but there is no info on partial support where :hover is only on `a` tag.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover says it existed  in IE4 for <a> elements, and support for all elements was added in IE7.

Comment: In addition, the [:hover reference page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848866(v=vs.85).aspx) on MSDN provides the gory details (though perhaps not as clearly as possible).